# Does passing an empty range (identical iterators) to an STL algorithm result in defined behavior?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Consider the following:

```
std::vector<int> vec(1); // vector has one element
std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), 42);
std::fill(vec.begin()+1, vec.end(), 43);
std::fill(vec.end(), vec.end(), 44);
```

Will all of the `std::fill` usages above result in defined behavior? Am I guaranteed that vec will remain unmodified? I'm inclined to think "yes", but I want to make sure the standard allows such usage.

Comment: This standard library defect report seems relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#212

Comment: This item in the standard library active issues list also seems relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1205

Comment: Actually, the root cause of those problems seems to be how to produce a return value given no input. `std::fill()` doesn't face that problem, it can simply do nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, if doesn't cause undefined behavior.

The standard defines *empty iterator range* in 24.1/7 and nowhere it says that supplying an empty range to `std::fill` algorithm causes undefined behavior.

This is actually what one would expect from a well-thought through implementation. With algorithms that handle emtpy range naturally, imposing the requirement to check for empty range on the caller would be a serious design error.

Comment: @AndreyT Isn't there an undefined behavior in his second example? I can see that `begin() == end()` when the range is empty, but `begin()+1` is not `end()`, right?

Comment: @Arak: In my second example, `begin()+1==end()` because `vec.size()==1` (note use of constructor taking size).

Comment: @Emile Sorry, lool it was me who missed that, sorry AndreyT :)

Comment: @AraK: No. Note that the vector is created with size 1 from the very beginning. So, `begin() + 1` is `end()`.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't believe it's specifically forbidden in the standard, I would say no. The standard requires that iterator ranges be of type `[first, last)` which includes `first` and everything up to but not including `last`. Passing in the same value for `first` and `last` doesn't make logical sense with this definition as it would be both included and not included, so I would expect to get undefined behavior back.

EDIT:
Cleaned up my initial response, and adding this: after brushing up on my [mathematical interval notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29), I've discovered that an interval of the form `[x,x)` is defined as the empty set. So my above answer is wrong -- I would NOT expect to get undefined behavior.

Comment: Which is it? "I would say yes" or "I would expect to get undefined behavior"?

Comment: I guess wasn't quite clear which question I was answering -- the 'yes' was in response to both the title question and the first question you asked in the text: "Will all of the std::fill usages above result in defined behavior?".

Comment: Oh wow. I misread the question multiple times, even when copy + pasting that. The answer should be "no". Sorry. *facepalm*

Comment: Still can't parse this response really. The range [x,x) is well defined as an empty range (24.1/7). It also translates naturally into the loop `(auto iter = x; iter != x; ++iter)`.

Comment: [first,last) isn't really read as "includes first and everything up to but not including last."  It's reads more like "first <= *x* < last", or "anything greater than or equal to first and less than last".  You see then, that if first == last, then no value of *x* satisfies the equation, so it is an empty set.  By the same token, [ *x*,*x* ) = ( *x*,*x* ] = ( *x*,*x* ) = ∅

Comment: +1 for link and the clarifications on [x,x) and empty set that resulted from your answer. :-)